# button corners are not clear in jquery mobile on android phone

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

I have two buttons in header section.both the buttons have round corner.but that round corners are not very clear I mean that corners appeared as dotted corners on android phone.I am using JQuery Mobile 1.2.0 and Cordova 2.0.0 and Android version is 2.3.4.Is their any solution for this.Please help me.

Comment: Please help me.Is there anyone having idea about this issue.please let me know guys.I am waiting for reply.Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be device resolution issue